# PHP code does not iterate to the next data variable in while loop (using bootstrap)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop, echo, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get a result from my PHP code that will iterate through an SQL database, make a table (in Bootstrap) of names, titles and phone numbers, and have each name, once clicked, trigger a modal that will display a name, photo, and small bio. These will all be echoed through variables taken through the variable assignment loop.

The current problem that I have is that while the modal itself is functional on click, the modal title only shows the first name shown in the database regardless of what name I click in the table. I have tried to move the echo ("$last_name, $first_name") assignment around to no avail. How can I get the while loop to account for the rest of the names in the table and iterate to that data in the SQL database?

```
     //Displays results from query (if valid)
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id           = $row["ID"];
    $last_name    = $row["last_name"];
    $first_name   = $row["first_name"];
    $job_title    = $row["job_title"];
    $phone_number = $row["phone_number"];
    $snetid       = $row["netid"];
?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#picbio">
                                        <?php

     alphabeticAnchorId($last, $last_name);
     echo "$last_name, $first_name";                                        

?>
                                        </a>
<div id="picbio" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>

        <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo "$first_name, $last_name"; ?></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body"><img src="empty_profile.gif" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Pic goes here"><br>
        <a href="mail goes here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Mail</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum in scelerisque elit, vel dictum justo. Nunc sit amet quam et justo tincidunt varius. Morbi tellus leo, hendrerit sit amet pellentesque quis, placerat eu libero. Quisque commodo, justo eget eleifend ultrices, tellus sem dignissim ipsum, sit amet suscipit massa massa eget eros. Donec tristique libero mi, id sagittis risus fermentum vel. Curabitur scelerisque lorem ut massa feugiat dignissim. Sed nec tortor vel eros accumsan egestas sed quis nulla. Curabitur a eros nec velit volutpat lobortis. Quisque a consequat elit. Aliquam gravida eros velit, in varius tellus dictum sit amet. Fusce id ex elit. </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: If all of that HTML is inside your loop then you're re-using the same `picbio` id for every iteration.  So in your client-side code when you tell it to show you the element with the id `picbio`, how is it going to know which one you mean?  Re-using an id in HTML is invalid, so the behavior on that markup is undefined.

Comment: So you are saying that for each name in the table the names have to have their own unique id's?

Comment: I'm saying that HTML elements require a unique `id` value.  In any system, two different things can not have the same "identifier", otherwise it's not really an "identifier".

Comment: In that case how exactly can I make unique id values for these names that will go to each respective div id? Can i possibly tie the id to one of the variables I have already made to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: If `$id` is unique for each record, then you might do something like: `<div id="picbio-<?php echo $id; ?>" ...`  That way the `id` in that HTML element would be unique for each iteration of the loop.  Anything which uses that `id` would have to be adjusted accordingly.  For example: `href="#picbio-<?php echo $id; ?>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [David stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587883/php-code-does-not-iterate-to-the-next-data-variable-in-while-loop-using-bootstr/42589049#comment72310198_42587883), you need to have a unique HTML ID for each modal so that the link will know which modal to open. Plus, multiple IDs of the same name is not valid in HTML. You can use the `$id` variable that you already have to make the HTML ID unique. So the opening tag for your modal would look like this:

```
<div id="picbio-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
```

And your link to open the modal would look like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#picbio-<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

to match the new modal ID.

Comment: Thanks! The code worked; I thought to use that initially but I did not actually implement it.